# How to call up calculations in custom methods to main Method

Tags: java, methods, return

I have a main method and 4 other function type methods which include calculations, however, How would I call each one up into the main and proceed to print out the calculations. Also I am currently getting a lot of syntax errors.

I've tried placing brackets  and braces when needed, however, that has just resulted into more errors. Also, I tried initializing Strings and integers elsewhere, which still seems to fail to work. Any help would be much appreciated!

Some syntax errors include: ';' expected on line 60

insert ';' to complete localVariableDelcartion on line 60

these errors are repeated for every line

```
import java.io.*;
//create the class


public class CirclemethodsFixedagain

{
    //main method
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {


        BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String numInput;
        String reqInput;
        String amountStr;
        double numInt = 0;
        double num = 0;


        System.out.println("This program will ask for a given user radius, then proceed to calculate the user input");
        System.out.println("The program will use four methods to achieve this, all calling back to the main method");
        System.out.println("Press any key to continue");
        numInput = myInput.readLine();

        // more user questions
        System.out.println("First, what would you like to calculate?");
        System.out.println("Enter '1' for Circumference, '2' for area, '3' for volume, or '4' for surface area");
        System.out.println("*NOTE* Pressing a key outside of this range or a regular character will re-prompt the original message");
        reqInput = myInput.readLine();
        numInt = Double.parseDouble(reqInput);

        // more user questions
        System.out.println("Now enter the radius of the required shape(Half of diameter)");
        System.out.println("*NOTE* Pressing a regular character will re-prompt the original message");
        numInput = myInput.readLine();
        num = Double.parseDouble(numInput);



    }
    //user created method, with each 
    public static int circlemethods(double circumference) throws IOException {

        {

            if (numInt == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("You chose to calculate circumference, given the radius :" + num);
                circumference = (Math.PI) * (2) * (num);
                System.out.print("The circumference of that sphere is :");
                return circumference;


            } 

            public static double circlemethods2 (double area)  throws IOException
            {   
                if (numInt == 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("You chose to calculate area, given the radius :" + num);
                    area = (Math.PI * num * num);
                    System.out.print("The area of the circle is :");

                    return area;   
                }   
            }     
            public static double circlemethods3 (double volume) throws IOException
            {
                if (numInput == 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("You chose to calculate volume, given the radius :" + num);
                    volume = (4 * Math.PI * num * num * num) / 3  ;
                    System.out.print("The volume of that sphere is : cm³");

                    return volume;
                }  
            }  
            public static double circlemethods4 (double surfaceArea) throws IOException  
                if (numInput == 4)
                {
                    System.out.println("You chose to calculate surface area, given the radius :" + num);
                    surfaceArea = 4 * Math.PI * num * num;
                    System.out.print("The Surface area of that sphere is :");

                    return surfaceArea;
                }
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your braces - the { and } characters - don't match up. I have fixed the indentation of the code in the question so that you can better see where the problem gets started - in the method `circlemethods`. Also, `circlemethods4` is missing its braces.

Keeping consistent indentation levels throughout the program makes these kinds of errors a lot more obvious to spot.

Answer (score 0):

Compilation errors are caused by:

1. You can not place methods inside other method, move circlemethods 2,3,4 outside the circlemethod1.
2. Your circlemethods don't see numInt local variable. It is declared in main method and it is visible only in that one.

I believe you don't need if statements at the begining of each circlemethods. You rather need something like that:

```
if (numInt == 1)
{ 
    circlemethod1(radius);
} else if (numInt == 2)  { 
    circlemethod2(radius);
}
```

etc. in your main method.

You can also change argument's name of each circlemethod, as I understood it is always radius. Current name of arguments is a good candidate for method name.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the inputs that will fix the problem :

1. You can't declare method inside a method, It's not JAVA syntax. Just check the bracing correctly. Use any IDE for doing the same.
2. Make numInt, num  as static (Class) variables. As you are using those in static method.
3. Use proper names and camelCasing nomenclature to name any method.
   |e.g calculateCircleArea(), calculateCircleVolume(), etc..

Hope this solves your problem.